# How to make correct string passing through function argument without allocating dynamic memory?

Tags: c++, c

```
void funct(char *err_msg)
{
    err_msg = "some_err";
}

void main()
{
    char err_msg[1024] = { 0 };
    funct(err_msg);
    //funct(&err_msg); //can't do this :(
    //after this err_msg still empty
}
```

I also tried

```
void funct(char err_msg[])
```

Comment: Your code allocate new memory. except for the pointer and probably for the literal.

Comment: Uhh yea, but I meant without using new / malloc to not deal with delete / free.

Comment: You have an array on stack no need for delete/free. by `funct(err_msg);` you send a pointer and the allocated memory for the previous array is used. So your code is correct and it does not allocate new array for the parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set `err_msg` inside `funct`, you need to pass a pointer to it

```
void funct(char **err_msg)
{
    *err_msg = "some_err";
}
```

and change `main` to just declare a `char*` and call `funct` like

```
char* err_msg;
funct(&err_msg);
```

Since you have allocated storage for a string in the calling function, it'd be easier to retain your current signature and copy into `err_msg` instead

```
void funct(char *err_msg)
{
    strcpy(err_msg, "some_err");
}
```